# How to configure kerberos authentication in java with MongoURI

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm able to access the particular mongo instance using plain authentication using the below format:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
```

What modifications do we need to do for the above URI for converting plain to kerberos authentication ?

Can anyone please suggest me regarding this issue ...

Comment: Did you read [this](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/connecting/authenticating/#kerberos-authentication)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the MongoClientURI

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://username%40REALM.com@host1/?authMechanism=GSSAPI");
```

Read more [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/connecting/authenticating/)

Comment: Where we need to give the location of the keytab file and krb5.conf and login.conf files ?

Comment: Read brief [here](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/reference/configuration/#configuration-kerberos-settings) on the kerberos.